# Glympse - Define Private Groups Using recipient's email addresses

Tags: glympse

When I define a private group I'm only presented with contracts for whom I have cell phone numbers. For typical glympses I can also select a recipient by their email address. How can I add recipients by email address when defining a private group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Glympse does not support private group invites via email. This is because a private group user needs to first verify their account with an SMS number. This is why private group invites can only be sent via SMS.